# Inline assembly branch target is out of range

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm new to assembly. And recently I need the inline assembly in Visual Studio 2013 to improve performance.

But I come to the branch target range problem:

```
_asm
{
    mov ecx, cnt;
    jecxz AZERO:
    AL1:
       /*Some operation codes here, but may be exceed 128 byte*/
    loop AL1;
    AZERO:
}
```

I know the reason is that the size of "operation codes" is exceed 128 bytes.

My simple solution is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    _asm
    {
       /*Some operation codes here, but may be exceed 128 byte*/
    }
}
```

This seems to work.

But I don't know whether this method is good enough?

And is there any good way to deal with the loop part without causing the branch range problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that `loop` and `jecxz`<sup>†</sup> are both short jump instructions. The C loop you had does not use `loop`; it uses `jcc` for branching (which has both short and near forms).

You can still use full assembly if you want. You just can't use `loop`:

```
    mov ecx, cnt
    jmp ATEST
AL1:
    /* fun happens here */
ATEST:
    dec ecx
    jns AL1
```

In technical terms<sup>‡</sup>:

- Short jumps use a signed 1-byte offset (from the next instruction), which provides a range of [-128, 128) (as you've already figured out).
- Near jumps use a signed 2-byte (in 16-bit mode) or 4-byte (in 32-bit and 64-bit modes) offset, which provide a range of [-32768, 32768) and [-2147483648, 2147483648), respectively.

  - In 16-bit and 32-bit modes, this means that near jumps can access any location in the current code segment.

† Note that `jecxz` is not technically a `jcc` instruction; it's outside the `jcc` opcode range, it doesn't check flags, and it has no corresponding `cmovcc` or `setcc` form.

‡ For completeness, `jmp` (but not `jcc`) also support near indirect jumps, far jumps, and far indirect jumps.

Comment: `jecxz` also has a short operand.

Comment: @gsg Technically `jecxz` is not a `jcc` instruction (it's outside the opcode range of the `jcc` instructions, it doesn't look at flags, and it doesn't have a `setcc` form), but since for some reason it's listed in the `jcc` section of the Intel manual, I'll update my answer to address that. Thanks!